# No MailTransportSender in WSO2 Micro Integrator?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-micro-integrator

I am working with Micro Integrator which is available inside latest Integration studio as run time. When I check the axis2.xml file to configure the MailTransportSender to send email notifications, I didn't see those properties.

I tried to copy those from ESB profile and tried to use in Micro Integrator. As soon as I start the server the properties are disappearing from axis2.xml file of Micro Integrator.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work in Micro Integrator. But the way you add them is different. Micro Integrator comes with new deployment toml file, where you have to edit all the configurations, which will overwrite the config files on startup ( also axis2 ). Please refer the documentation https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/#configuring-the-mailto-transport for more details.

Thanks !
Nirothipan

Comment: Please include in your answer an actual solution, this refers to documentation (without a link even).

Comment: Thanks for responding @Nirothipan. But, I don't see much documentation regarding this. Can you please share any link if you have, where the configuration procedure of axi2 file is mentioned.

Comment: Hi Tejas
Kindly refer https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/#configuring-the-mailto-transport
Thanks

Comment: Hi Nirothipan, Thanks for the needful help. As you rightly pointed, there is a file called deployment.toml where we need to add the transport senders and receivers which will be updated those parameters to axis2.xml on server restart. I am able to configure SMTP transport and able to send notifications. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the following to the deployment.toml under the run configuration inside the 8.2 studio: (my concern is the last one which is text/html), but it is not working, although adding the same to axis2.xml in a MI standalone (outside the studio) works fine.

```
[message_builder]    
application_xml = "org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"
form_urlencoded = "org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"
multipart_form_data = "org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"
text_plain = "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"
application_json = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
json_badgerfish = "org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishOMBuilder"
text_javascript = "org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder"
octet_stream = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"
application_binary = "org.apache.axis2.format.BinaryBuilder"
text_html = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"

[message_formatter]
form_urlencoded = "org.apache.synapse.commons.formatters.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"
multipart_form_data = "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"
application_xml = "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"
text_xml = "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"
soap_xml = "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"
text_plain = "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"
application_json = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
json_badgerfish = "org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishMessageFormatter"
text_javascript = "org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"
octet_stream = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"
application_binary = "org.apache.axis2.format.BinaryFormatter"
text_html = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
```